# How to add Multilevel ListView Command Set buttons using SPFX Extensiton?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset

[image]

In `manifest.json` file I have structure like:

```
"items": {
"COMMAND_1": {
  "title": { "default": "Command One" },
  "iconImageUrl": "_layouts/15/images/itslidelibrary.png",
  "type": "command",
},
"COMMAND_2": {
  "title": { "default": "Command Two" },
  "iconImageUrl": "_layouts/15/images/dldsln16.png",
  "type": "command"
}
}
```

How can I add multilevel buttons/commands in it as shown in above figure?